# How to trigger ngOnChanges to update my formgroup

Tags: angular, formgroups, ngonchanges

My parent component subscribes to param changes:

```
this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(params => {
      const changedQueryParams = {};
      params.keys.forEach((key) => {
        const values = params.getAll(key);
        if (values.length > 0) {
          changedQueryParams[key] = values;
        }
      });
      this.queryParams = changedQueryParams;
```

populating an object:
`queryParams = {};`

I pass it to my child component which has a FormGroup

```
<child-component
[queryParams]="queryParams" 
></child-component
```

the child component's variable:
`@Input() queryParams= {};`

The ngOnChanges:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any): void {
      if(changes.queryParams && changes.isFirsChange){
        this.filterFormGroup.patchValue(changes.queryParams, {emitEvent:true})
      }
  }
```

I've tried defining the object in the parent component based off other answers I've seen on here:

`this.queryParams = {...changedQueryParams}`

I did some `console.logs` but nothing is printing out.
Why isn't my formgroup updating?

Comment: Remove take(1) inside pipe

Comment: Right we don't want first value. Left in during the debugging process. Took it out

Comment: Have it helped?

Comment: Removing take(1) did not help

Comment: this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
      map((params: ParamMap) => console.log(params.get('name OfYourParam'))),
    ); What does it print?